# How can I make ParallelDo faster than Do?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, parallelization, procedural-programming

I am trying to optimize my code as much as possible. So first I used a compile and now I am trying to parallelize the code in order to make it faster because in the end I will need to make a loop that will iterate the rho function several times.

```
ps = 8.85*10^(-12);
q = 80;
m = 50;
L = 2;
nparticles = 100000;
ngrid = 10000;
vth = 2;
u = 1;

dx = L/ngrid;

dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
   1./(2.*Pi*Power[vth, 2.])^(0.5)*Exp[-(vi - u)^2./(2.*vth^2.)] + 
    1./(2.*Pi*Power[vth, 2])^(0.5)*
     Exp[-(vi + u)^2./(2. vth^2)], {vi, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Method -> "Normalize"];

rho = Compile[{{xp, _Real, 1}, {xg, _Real, 
    1}, {carga, _Real}, {np, _Real}, {ng, _Real}, {dx, _Real}},
  n = ng + 1;
  ρ = Table[carga*np/(dx*ng), n];
  ρ[[ng + 1]] = 0;
  
  Do[If[Abs[xp[[i]] - xg[[j]]] <= 
     dx, ρ[[j]] = ρ[[j]] - 
      carga*(1 - (Abs[xp[[i]] - xg[[j]]])/dx)/dx; r += 1, 0] , {i, 1, 
    np}, {j, 1, ng + 1}];
  ρ[[1]] = ρ[[1]] + ρ[[ng + 1]];]

v = RandomVariate[dist, nparticles];
x = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, L}], nparticles];
r = 0;

xgrid = Range[0, L, dx] // N;
rho[x, xgrid, q, nparticles, ngrid, dx]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

r

However when I substitute the Do in the rho compile for a parallelDo the code becomes 5 or 6 times slower.

How can I use parallelization to make the code faster? If I do something like

```
t=1;    
While[t<1000, ParallelDo[rho[x, xgrid, q, nparticles, ngrid, dx],{i,1,nparticles}];t+=1];
```

is ParallelDo effecient?

Comment: I cannot try it at the moment, but have you tried to use the option `Parallelization->True` in the `Compile` code? And not using the `ParallelDo`

Comment: Parallelization->True makes the code slightly slower or with the same speed than it is with a simple Do

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `Parallelization->True` parallelizes only if the function has also the `Listable` attribute and if the function is called in a listable way (e.g. at least one of the input arguments is actually a list of inputs). To my knowledge, `ParallelDo` cannot be compiled by `Compile`.